# trying to insert a JOptionPane to a program

Tags: java, swing

This program was pretty much re-written by a wonderful person on this site. I'm trying to dabble with it and i'm on the final step. I'm trying to make my messages come up as JoptionPane's, and i need the good messages to have the PLAIN_MESSAGE icon and the error messages to have the error one. So far i can make the boxes appear but i'm not sure how to have it prompt the user to enter an answer into the box and have the result also pop up in a message box. As of right now it opens the optionpane but makes the user type the answer in the box at the bottom of eclipse.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Easter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputted = getResult(s);
        while(inputted <= 0)
        {
            String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Expected a positive year. Please try again:", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("You entered " + result);
            inputted = getResult(s);
        }
        System.out.println(getEasterSundayDate(inputted));
    }

    private static int getResult(Scanner s)
    {
        while(!s.hasNextInt())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Expected a valid year. Please try again:\n>");
            s.nextLine();
        }
        return s.nextInt();
    }

    public static String getEasterSundayDate(int year)
    {
        int a = year % 19,
            b = year / 100,
            c = year % 100,
            d = b / 4,
            e = b % 4,
            g = (8 * b + 13) / 25,
            h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30,
            j = c / 4,
            k = c % 4,
            m = (a + 11 * h) / 319,
            r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7,
            n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25,
            p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;

        String result;
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:
                result = "January ";
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "February ";
                break;
            case 3:
                result = "March ";
                break;
            case 4:
                result = "April ";
                break;
            case 5:
                result = "May ";
                break;
            case 6:
                result = "June ";
                break;
            case 7:
                result = "July ";
                break;
            case 8:
                result = "August ";
                break;
            case 9:
                result = "September ";
                break;
            case 10:
                result = "October ";
                break;
            case 11:
                result = "November ";
                break;
            case 12:
                result = "December ";
                break;
            default:
                result = "error";
        }

        return result + p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by taking a look at [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)).  There are a few varients, but the linked version allows you to specify the message type

You should also have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

As an example...

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Expected a positive year. Please try again:", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
System.out.println("You entered " + result);
result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday", "Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
System.out.println("You entered " + result);
result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday");
System.out.println("You entered " + result);
```

**Updated**

For simplicity, I've maintained the core portion in the `main` method, you could off load the validation of the value to another method, but this gets the basic idea flowing...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a year to calculate Easter Sunday", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    int inputted = 0;
    do {
        try {
            inputted = Integer.parseInt(value);
            if (inputted <= 0) {
                inputted = 0;
                value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Expected a positive year. Please try again:", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            inputted = 0;
            value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, value + " is not a valid number. Please try again:", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } while (inputted == 0);
}
```

Comment: Iv been reading tutorials but the thing that kind of confuses me is how to put it into my current program. It was simple to get the box to show the message but how my results are set up, i have no idea how to go about making that a joptionpane

Comment: So, instead of reading the input from `s`, you would use the input returned from the `InputDialog`, see update for examples...

Comment: So by adding your code it worked, kind of. It came up as the error first, and then two dialog boxes but nothing resulted in an answer. I tried moving things around and now nothing proves a result and the error message wont pop up when i purposely mess up. Obviously its probably because your input was only an example, but im new and stupid, nevermind very slow. I edited OP's code. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Basically, you can no longer user `Scanner`.  Any where you use `Scanner`, you need to replace it with either the result of a previous call to `JOptionpane` or `JOptionPane` itself...

Comment: Or i have another edited option i could use which was my orig code with message changed to input. But that creates the text box but yields no answer, and when typed a word to error it the error doesnt show

Comment: So this would be a lengthy thing for me to convert and fix wouldnt it?

Comment: I'd start with a copy of the program, so you have a reference point to back to.  I would then remove the import statement for `Scanner`, this will break your program and show you where you need to replace the use of `Scanner` with `JOptionPane`.  I would then isolate small sections of your code and get those sections working (either by writing test classes, small snippets of functional code or commenting out the sections you don't want to deal with).  Yes, it might take some time, but it will be a worthwhile learning experience...

Comment: Well the reason why i may not want to dedicate that much time is because i may drop this class, its miserable and taught by a horrible prof. But i will give this a try because i'm definitely wanting to show him i can do this. So question. int inputted = getResult(s); how would i turn that into a joptionpane? It refers back to the scanner which will be gone. Not sure how to modify

Comment: I'm still confused. But its not you, its me. I do appreciate you help! This was optional to use the JOptionPane, but i cant see staying up late working on a class i plan on dropping. Ill make this as solved, i thank you good sir.

Comment: I copied it down to a note pad and titled it. Definitely helpful info for next time! I told him i ran out of time today and would give it a shot next time. Waiting for his normal lousy response of something like "should of tried harder, but ok.". Thanks again :P